# Taylor Series approximation in R

Tags: r, taylor-series

What if I need to calculate the Taylor Series approximation for a function of two variables, is it possible in R? My function of interest is e raised to the power of the sum of variables x1 and x2: e^(x1 + x2)

Since there's `taylor` [function](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/pracma/docs/taylor) in `pracma` library, I try something like this:

```
func <- function(x) exp(1)^(x[1]+x[2])
vars <- c(0, 0) # evaluated at point (0,0)
taylor(func, vars, 2)
```

But R says `Error in fderiv(f, x0, i) : Function 'f' must first be vectorized: Vectorize(f).`

So, what am I doing wrong and is possible at all for a function of two variables?

Comment: `taylor` only supports functions of one variable. You should do this with pencil and paper.

Comment: Thanks, Roland. Somehow I felt so :). Tried Wolfram|Alpha, too, but again, it was stuck to one variable, unfortunately :(.

Comment: As  e^(x1+x2) = e^x1 * e^x2 , you can multiply these two Taylor series to get the series for your function.

Comment: Hans, thanks for that hint (stupid me!). That's interesting and should be right, as far as I understand, but my answer (1/2 * x^2 * e^x * e^y + x * e^x * e^y + 1) * (1/2 * y^2 * e^x * e^y + y * e^x * e^y + 1) was marked as wrong :).

Comment: Did you try and reorder the product to something like: 1 + (x1+x2) + (x1+x2)^2/2 + ...